# Bayesian model with unknown mean and variance

Tags: regression, bayesian

$$
y_{i} \sim N(\mu_i,\sigma) \\
\mu_i=\beta_0+\beta_1X_i \\
\beta_0, \beta_1 \sim N(0, 3) \\
\sigma \sim half-cauchy(0, 2.5)
$$

It's a Bayesian linear regression, and I want to find 'posterior distribution'.

Comment: This does not have an analytic solution.  What is your question?  This appears to be a statement, not a question.